# Query to collect all indexes from a specific table and generate the drop command

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I'm trying to code something to select all indexes from a specific table and outupt de command to drop them all, I think is something like that, but the syntax isnt correct at all. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
SELECT
  'DROP INDEX ' + i.* + ' ON ' + TableName = t.Name
  + ';'
FROM
  sys.indexes i
  INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE
  T.Name = 'TableXYZ';
```

Comment: Please show the example of the result you want to get.

Comment: your string concatenate syntax is wrong. You can't concatenate with `i.*` and you can't have a assignment in between concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give, I think, the desired result.

```
SELECT 'DROP INDEX ' + i.name + ' ON ' + t.Name + ';' as sql_drop
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE T.Name = 'test'
and i.name is not null;
```

You can also concatenate with CONCAT:

```
SELECT concat('DROP INDEX ',i.name,' ON ',t.Name,';') as sql_drop
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
WHERE T.Name = 'test'
and i.name is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You **must** also add `QUOTENAME` in order to quote the index names correctly. You should also specify the schema.

```sql
SELECT
  'DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(i.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.Name) + ';'
FROM
  sys.indexes i
  JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
  JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
  t.Name = 'TableXYZ';
```